# If $o(a)=n$ then $o(a^r)=n$ if and only if $\gcd(n,r)=1$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ be a group and let $a\in G$ . Suppose $o(a)=n$. Then $o(a^r)=n$ if and only if $\gcd(n,r)=1$.
I am able to prove the converse but not sure about implication statement,  i.e., $o(a^r)=n$ then $\gcd(n,r)=1$.

My attempt:

Let $\gcd(n,r)=d$. Then $\frac{r}{d}$ and $\frac{n}{d}$ are integers.

Then $(a^r)^\frac{n}{d}=(a^n)^\frac{r}{d}=e$.
Since $o(a^r)=n$ we get $n\mid \frac{n}{d}$. Then $n\leq\frac{n}{d}$. So $d=1$. Is this correct?

(I know there are some proofs showing $o(a^r)=\frac{n}{\gcd(n,r)}$ using this we can prove above result but I wanted to prove it directly.)

Comment: Yes, I think it is flawless.

Comment: what is $o$ ????

Comment: It is order of element a